# Converting a function based innerHTML for embedding in an XHTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, innerhtml

I have a chunk of coding that I've written, but it uses innerHTML, and the page that I am attempting to load it into requires XHTML.

Can anyone help me get it converted?

Currently, it is pulling 3 sets of variables based on what is selected from my drop down menu.

It then should populate the variables within the same page a box that outputs the variables.

the part of my coding where the innerHTML resides is below, how do I make it workable in XHTML, so that I have a small box show with the specific data that's populated?

```
function init(){ 
   f=document.getElementById('form0');
   p=document.getElementById('locations')
   i=document.getElementById('info');

   f.reset();
   p.onchange=function() {
if(this.value!=='') {
   n=this.value;
   i.innerHTML=
           '<div>Location: <span id="pname">'+pn[n]+'<\/span><\/div>'+
           '<div>Username & Password: <span id="ipadr">'+ip[n]+'<\/span><\/div>'+
           '<div>Link to supply ordering: <a id="scall" href="'+sc[n]+'">LOGIN HERE<\/a><\/div>';
   i.className='';  
   }
else {
   i.className='hide';
   }
   }
}
   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);
})();
```

Comment: Are you saying it does not work with your page? In what way? Are you actually serving XHTML or just using the doctype?

Comment: The drop down menu works correctly, but when I select the appropriate listing, the innerHTML window does not display.

If I open my original .xhtml file through a browser, it works correctly.

I know the wiki page that I am pasting it in operates on xhtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content as such is not valid xhtml because of the `&` character in the second div. In xhtml, `&` is taken to mean the beginning of an entity (http://www.elizabethcastro.com/html/extras/entities.html).

Try replacing `&` with `&amp;` instead.

Comment: Replaced the & with 'and' and it let me compile the data, but the editor then wiped out all my coding, so apparently there's something within the webpage i'm importing into that won't let me use actual coding...

Moving back to what I was originally trying to get working, the iFrame...


Thanks...